# Reading nested JSON in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, parsing

I'm working for the first time with JSON. Please help me out. This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
"metadata":[["15038",
        [["object_id",
                "15368"
            ],
            ["data_map",
                [["name",
                        "Sashimi"
                    ],
                    ["recipe_image",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<ezimage serial_number=\"1\" is_valid=\"1\" filename=\"Sashimi.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" basename=\"Sashimi\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi.jpg\" original_filename=\"Sashimi bredde.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"1200\" height=\"690\" alternative_text=\"Sashimi\" alias_key=\"1293033771\" timestamp=\"1291644679\"><original attribute_id=\"166714\" attribute_version=\"1\" attribute_language=\"nor-NO\"/><information Height=\"690\" Width=\"1200\" IsColor=\"1\" ByteOrderMotorola=\"0\" CCDWidth=\"35mm\" ApertureFNumber=\"f/8.0\" UserComment=\"\" UserCommentEncoding=\"UNDEFINED\" Thumbnail.FileType=\"2\" Thumbnail.MimeType=\"image/jpeg\"><serialized name=\"ifd0\" data=\"a:15:{s:10:&quot;ImageWidth&quot;;i:4368;s:11:&quot;ImageLength&quot;;i:2912;s:13:&quot;BitsPerSample&quot;;a:3:{i:0;i:8;i:1;i:8;i:2;i:8;}s:11:&quot;Compression&quot;;i:1;s:25:&quot;PhotometricInterpretation&quot;;i:2;s:4:&quot;Make&quot;;s:5:&quot;Canon&quot;;s:5:&quot;Model&quot;;s:12:&quot;Canon EOS 5D&quot;;s:11:&quot;Orientation&quot;;i:1;s:11:&quot;XResolution&quot;;s:4:&quot;72/1&quot;;s:11:&quot;YResolution&quot;;s:4:&quot;72/1&quot;;s:19:&quot;PlanarConfiguration&quot;;i:1;s:14:&quot;ResolutionUnit&quot;;i:2;s:8:&quot;Software&quot;;s:29:&quot;Adobe Photoshop CS4 Macintosh&quot;;s:8:&quot;DateTime&quot;;s:19:&quot;2010:01:13 20:36:26&quot;;s:16:&quot;Exif_IFD_Pointer&quot;;i:300;}\"/><array name=\"exif\"><item key=\"ExposureTime\" base64=\"1\">MS84</item><item key=\"FNumber\" base64=\"1\">OC8x</item><item key=\"ExposureProgram\" base64=\"1\">MQ==</item><item key=\"ISOSpeedRatings\" base64=\"1\">MjAw</item><item key=\"ExifVersion\" base64=\"1\">MDIyMQ==</item><item key=\"DateTimeOriginal\" base64=\"1\">MjAxMDowMToxMSAyMjo0MjozMw==</item><item key=\"DateTimeDigitized\" base64=\"1\">MjAxMDowMToxMSAyMjo0MjozMw==</item><item key=\"ComponentsConfiguration\" base64=\"1\">AQIDAA==</item><item key=\"ShutterSpeedValue\" base64=\"1\">MTk2NjA4LzY1NTM2</item><item key=\"ApertureValue\" base64=\"1\">MzkzMjE2LzY1NTM2</item><item key=\"ExposureBiasValue\" base64=\"1\">MC8x</item><item key=\"MeteringMode\" base64=\"1\">NQ==</item><item key=\"Flash\" base64=\"1\">MTY=</item><item key=\"FocalLength\" base64=\"1\">MTAwLzE=</item><item key=\"UserComment\" base64=\"1\">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</item><item key=\"FlashPixVersion\" base64=\"1\">MDEwMA==</item><item key=\"ColorSpace\" base64=\"1\">NjU1MzU=</item><item key=\"ExifImageWidth\" base64=\"1\">NDM2OA==</item><item key=\"ExifImageLength\" base64=\"1\">MjkxMg==</item><item key=\"FocalPlaneXResolution\" base64=\"1\">NDM2ODAwMC8xNDE1</item><item key=\"FocalPlaneYResolution\" base64=\"1\">MjkxMjAwMC85NDI=</item><item key=\"FocalPlaneResolutionUnit\" base64=\"1\">Mg==</item><item key=\"CustomRendered\" base64=\"1\">MA==</item><item key=\"ExposureMode\" base64=\"1\">MQ==</item><item key=\"WhiteBalance\" base64=\"1\">MA==</item><item key=\"SceneCaptureType\" base64=\"1\">MA==</item></array></information><alias name=\"small\" filename=\"Sashimi_small.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_small.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"293\" height=\"168\" alias_key=\"217385800\" timestamp=\"1323807975\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"large\" filename=\"Sashimi_large.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_large.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"618\" height=\"355\" alias_key=\"2890659831\" timestamp=\"1319639601\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"gallerywidethumbnail\" filename=\"Sashimi_gallerywidethumbnail.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_gallerywidethumbnail.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"150\" height=\"86\" alias_key=\"1571581304\" timestamp=\"1322682704\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"gallerythumbnail\" filename=\"Sashimi_gallerythumbnail.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_gallerythumbnail.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"105\" height=\"60\" alias_key=\"27904634\" timestamp=\"1323764644\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"max\" filename=\"Sashimi_max.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_max.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"943\" height=\"542\" alias_key=\"3797359156\" timestamp=\"1323706767\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"imagelarge\" filename=\"Sashimi_imagelarge.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_imagelarge.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"550\" height=\"316\" alias_key=\"4054437477\" timestamp=\"1318593167\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"medium\" filename=\"Sashimi_medium.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_medium.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"455\" height=\"261\" alias_key=\"169029957\" timestamp=\"1318593168\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"articleimage\" filename=\"Sashimi_articleimage.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_articleimage.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"170\" height=\"97\" alias_key=\"2326327281\" timestamp=\"1318593168\" is_valid=\"1\"/><alias name=\"infoboximage\" filename=\"Sashimi_infoboximage.jpg\" suffix=\"jpg\" dirpath=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO\" url=\"var/ezflow_site/storage/images/b2c/oppskrifter/norge/sashimi/166714-1-nor-NO/Sashimi_infoboximage.jpg\" mime_type=\"image/jpeg\" width=\"75\" height=\"43\" alias_key=\"2355174995\" timestamp=\"1318593168\" is_valid=\"1\"/></ezimage>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["photographers_name",
                        "Synøve Dreyer"
                    ],
                    ["recipe_images",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<related-objects><relation-list/></related-objects>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["recipe_images_chooser",
                        "https://market.seafood.no/SearchMediasForExternalApplication.do?globalSearchTerm=&validTo=12%2F01%2F2012&hookUrl=http://nor.eksportfis.prod.dedicated100.uk.webdeal.no/brandmakerphoto/photoupdater/15368/24/658&hookId=15368/24/658&destinationSize=1200x690&distort=no&imageEngine=true"
                    ],
                    ["show_on_front",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["star_rating",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["servings",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["main_menu_categorization",
                        ", Gjester_Vennebesøk, Kampanje_Sushi, Kos_Helgekos, Hverdag_Sunn"
                    ],
                    ["categorization",
                        ", Vanskelighetsgrad_Middels, Type rett_Sushi og sashimi, Fisketype_Laks, Fisketype_Kveite, Fisketype_Kamskjell, Tilberedningstid_20 - 40 min"
                    ],
                    ["teaser",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<section xmlns:image=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/image/\" xmlns:xhtml=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/xhtml/\" xmlns:custom=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/custom/\"><paragraph>I Japan serverer man gjerne ponzusaus til sashimi. Ingrediensene til en slik saus kan være vanskelig å få tak i her i Norge, så her foreslår vi to andre sauser som også passer godt til sashimi. &amp;nbsp;</paragraph></section>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["ingredients",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<section xmlns:image=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/image/\" xmlns:xhtml=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/xhtml/\" xmlns:custom=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/custom/\"/>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["main_text",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<section xmlns:image=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/image/\" xmlns:xhtml=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/xhtml/\" xmlns:custom=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/custom/\"><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\"><ul><li><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\">Her kan du velge om du vil lage en soyasaus med sesam og lime eller en sashimidressing. Du kan også bruke soyasaus hvis du ønsker det.</paragraph></li></ul></paragraph><section><section><section><header>Soyasaus med sesam og lime</header><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\"><ul><li><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\">Press saften av lime i soyasausen og rør inn sesamolje.</paragraph></li></ul></paragraph></section></section></section><section><section><section><header>Sashimidressing</header><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\"><ul><li><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\">Finhakk løk, sylteagurk, stangselleri, og kapers. </paragraph></li><li><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\">Bland dette sammen med de øvrige ingrediensene, og la det stå å trekke litt i kjøleskapet. Mirin er en risvin med lavt alkoholinnhold som fås kjøpt i asiatiske forretninger.</paragraph></li></ul></paragraph></section></section></section><section><section><section><header>Sashimi</header><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\"><ul><li><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\">Skjær sjømaten i tynne skiver og anrett pent på et fat sammen.</paragraph></li><li><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\">Server med soyasaus med sesam og lime eller sashimidressing, og gjerne tynne strimler av rettich og gulrot.</paragraph></li></ul></paragraph><paragraph><emphasize>Ønsker du å <strong>lære mer om sushi</strong> finner du nyttig informasjon <link target=\"_self\" url_id=\"858\">her. </link></emphasize></paragraph></section></section></section></section>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["author",
                        "Norwegian Seafood Export Council"
                    ],
                    ["youtube_video",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<section xmlns:image=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/image/\" xmlns:xhtml=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/xhtml/\" xmlns:custom=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/custom/\"><paragraph xmlns:tmp=\"http://ez.no/namespaces/ezpublish3/temporary/\"><literal class=\"html\">&lt;object width=\"618\" height=\"372\"&gt;&lt;param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/Y69-Ta0_Tfc?fs=1&amp;amp;hl=nb_NO&amp;amp;rel=0\"&gt;&lt;/param&gt;&lt;param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"&gt;&lt;/param&gt;&lt;param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"&gt;&lt;/param&gt;&lt;embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/Y69-Ta0_Tfc?fs=1&amp;amp;hl=nb_NO&amp;amp;rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"618\" height=\"372\"&gt;&lt;/embed&gt;&lt;/object&gt;</literal></paragraph></section>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["main_menu_categorization_selector",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<related-objects><relation-list><relation-item priority=\"1\" contentobject-id=\"11122\" contentobject-version=\"2\" node-id=\"10948\" parent-node-id=\"10947\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"9cc7b4ba9b47c94da56c269e86cb03c2\"/><relation-item priority=\"2\" contentobject-id=\"31635\" contentobject-version=\"1\" node-id=\"28570\" parent-node-id=\"16579\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"95517e870ac58cc8f70af70e2d798a89\"/><relation-item priority=\"3\" contentobject-id=\"220\" contentobject-version=\"5\" node-id=\"193\" parent-node-id=\"173\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"0b34aeb34a5ff3abe60d77c525fcd7d1\"/><relation-item priority=\"4\" contentobject-id=\"224\" contentobject-version=\"5\" node-id=\"197\" parent-node-id=\"174\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"8e5a6a212cbea6bf25d9180ecf77ffbb\"/></relation-list></related-objects>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["categorization_selector",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<related-objects><relation-list><relation-item priority=\"1\" contentobject-id=\"104\" contentobject-version=\"20\" node-id=\"106\" parent-node-id=\"100\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"67dc83cb472f98c38f1de19611c47235\"/><relation-item priority=\"2\" contentobject-id=\"2488\" contentobject-version=\"7\" node-id=\"2465\" parent-node-id=\"260\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"f9c5ba8b49190839b20d5d0b97f12fa1\"/><relation-item priority=\"3\" contentobject-id=\"1623\" contentobject-version=\"9\" node-id=\"1600\" parent-node-id=\"98\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"verticalsite_18271\"/><relation-item priority=\"4\" contentobject-id=\"1632\" contentobject-version=\"7\" node-id=\"1609\" parent-node-id=\"98\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"verticalsite_18280\"/><relation-item priority=\"5\" contentobject-id=\"1641\" contentobject-version=\"7\" node-id=\"1618\" parent-node-id=\"98\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"verticalsite_18292\"/><relation-item priority=\"6\" contentobject-id=\"107\" contentobject-version=\"16\" node-id=\"109\" parent-node-id=\"99\" contentclass-id=\"49\" contentclass-identifier=\"tag\" contentobject-remote-id=\"11e07e691070c3a8cfcfc6a83402988c\"/></relation-list></related-objects>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["ambassador_article",
                        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\u000a<related-objects><relation-list/></related-objects>\u000a"
                    ],
                    ["comments",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["seo_keywords",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["meta_description",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["publish_date",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["unpublish_date",
                        ""
                    ],
                    ["manually_related_recipes",
                        null
                    ],
                    ["show_automatically_related_recipes",
                        null
                    ],
                    ["manually_related_articles",
                        null
                    ],
                    ["show_automatically_related_articles",
                        null
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
}
```

Please let me know how I can get the name and `recipe_image` from above JSON. What I have searched so far are these links:

[help me to parse JSON value using JSONTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835638/help-me-to-parse-json-value-using-jsontouch)

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/81895-nested-json-nsdictionary-integer.html

[How do I parse this nested JSON output in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240486/how-do-i-parse-this-nested-json-output-in-objective-c)

[How to parse nested JSON objects with JSON framework and Objective-C/iPhone/Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692247/how-to-parse-nested-json-objects-with-json-framework-and-objective-c-iphone-xcod)

[How can I pull out nested JSON values in a collection in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153042/how-can-i-pull-out-nested-json-values-in-a-collection-in-objective-c)

http://s316.codeinspot.com/q/2402326

Comment: This is strange behavior to nest XML in JSON data...

Comment: I know it it strange, but i got this xml from my client to read ,is there any way to read this ???

Comment: You say you've read those links, but you havent said what you've actually tried to do, or what problems you have.

Comment: do you want xml content from json file??

Comment: actually i want to get the values of name, recipe_image and caterisation_selector from above json, nut dont know how ... As m working first time on json....

Comment: Hope this link help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661845/json-parser-example-for-ios5

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is using SBJson reader found on github https://github.com/stig/json-framework and then go find yourself a XML parser, [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) has great bench marking of the different XML parser out there for iOS

Comment: In IOS 5.0 Apple included the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON. 
Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/ for the details